# Cypress, Jenkins - allure-results folder missing at the end of execution

Tags: jenkins, cypress, allure

**Context**
Jenkins version: 2.440.1

Job type: Freestyle

Allure plugin version: Version: 2.31.1

Allure commandline version: 2.24.1

**Problem description**

1. When I run my Cypress Automation tests local without Jenkins then allure-results is generating
2. When I run jenkins on localhost:8181, then also allure-results is
   generated
3. But when I run Jenkins on localhost:8181, as a GitHub project, then allure-results folder is not generating.

Error logs

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/cvcAdmin/.jenkins/workspace/freestyleDemoJob
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential tesUsername
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://bitbucket.org/klite/cypress-automation

git init /Users/cvcAdmin/.jenkins/workspace/freestyleDemoJob # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/klite/cypress-automation
git --version # timeout=10
git --version # 'git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials tesUsername
git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://bitbucket.org/klite/cypress-automation +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/ # timeout=10
git config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket.org/klite/cypress-automation # timeout=10
git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/ # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/demo-jenkins-setup^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 3115642e22e23800bf11ead495985dabc0c71b1f (refs/remotes/origin/demo-jenkins-setup)
git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
git checkout -f 3115642e22e23800bf11ead495985dabc0c71b1f # timeout=10
Commit message: "cypress.config.js edited"
git rev-list --no-walk 3115642e22e23800bf11ead495985dabc0c71b1f # timeout=10
[freestyleDemoJob] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/gc/51_g04r14fz6m1zhr9zndx0m0000gn/T/jenkins6055224141279522555.sh


node -v
v21.6.2
npm -v
10.2.4
npm install
npm WARN deprecated @types/cypress@1.1.3: This is a stub types definition for cypress (https://cypress.io/). cypress provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/cypress installed!
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @cypress/xpath@2.0.3: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-inject@3.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-inject.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated cucumber-expressions@8.3.0: This package is now published under @cucumber/cucumber-expressions
npm WARN deprecated gherkin@5.0.0: This package is now published under @cucumber/gherkin
npm WARN deprecated cucumber@6.0.7: Cucumber is publishing new releases under @cucumber/cucumber
added 1169 packages, and audited 1170 packages in 1m

155 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details

5 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 1 high)

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run npm audit for details.

npx cypress run --spec cypress/integration/features/login --headed --browser electron
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63788/devtools/browser/fcd99136-83e4-4320-9b9a-27562e7dc5fa
Couldn't find tsconfig.json. tsconfig-paths will be skipped

Opening /dev/tty failed (6): Device not configured
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
�[90m====================================================================================================�[

Running: �[90mlogin.feature�[39m �[90m(1 of 1)�[39m

��[0m klite Login tests�[0m
**************************** Test Started ****************************


Opening /dev/tty failed (6): Device not configured
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
�[90m====================================================================================================�[39m

[freestyleDemoJob] $ /Users/cvcAdmin/.jenkins/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/Allure_2.27.0/bin/allure generate /Users/cvcAdmin/.jenkins/workspace/freestyleDemoJob/allure-results -c -o /Users/cvcAdmin/.jenkins/workspace/freestyleDemoJob/allure-report
Report successfully generated to /Users/cvcAdmin/.jenkins/workspace/freestyleDemoJob/allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Is Allure preparing a log file so that we can see what's failing to create `allure-results` folder? Are there any other ways to debug this issue?